# How to remove a virtualenv created by "pipenv run"

Tags: pipenv

I am learning Python virtual environment. In one of my small projects I ran

```
pipenv run python myproject.py
```

and it created a virtualenv for me in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.virtualenvs`

I found it also created or modified some files under my project source code directory. I am just wondering how to cleanly delete this virtualenv and reverse my project back to a no-virtualenv state.

I am using python 3.6.4, and PyCharm.

Answer (score 557, accepted):

You can run the `pipenv` command with the `--rm` option as in:

```
pipenv --rm
```

This will remove the virtualenv created for you under ~/.virtualenvs

See https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/cli/#cmdoption-pipenv-rm

Comment: So ... that works if I still have the directory containing the `Pipfile`.  But what if I've deleted it?

Comment: @offby1 just manually delete it in the terminal by going to `~/.virtualenvs` and removing the directory. The directory is named after the project plus a hash of its location e.g. `projectname-Kovkq8ZR`

Comment: if there is a command to create an env there should be a command to remove one, not a switch.

Comment: i want to delete a specific virtualenv instead of all, what will do?

Comment: @BaneeIshaqueK `pipenv --rm` does only remove the `virtualenv` for the associated `Pipfile` in the current directory.

Comment: It also works for the virtual environment created by `pipenv install` command.

Comment: @Tom for me it was in .local/share/virtualenvs/

Comment: Note this does not remove the associated `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files (in the current directory)!

Comment: The link is broken, the old link from the history of the post works.

Answer (score 52):

#### In root of project where Pipfile is located you could run

```bash
pipenv --venv
```

#### which returns

- Linux/OS X:

```bash
/Users/your_user_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/model-N-S4uBGU
```

- Windows:

```
C:\Users\your_user_name\.virtualenvs\model-N-S4uBGU
```

#### and then remove this env by typing

- Bash/Zsh:

```bash
rm -rf /Users/your_user_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/model-N-S4uBGU
```

- Powershell:

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force 'C:\Users\your_user_name\.virtualenvs\model-N-S4uBGU'
```

- Command Prompt

```bash
rmdir /s "C:\Users\your_user_name\.virtualenvs\model-N-S4uBGU"
```

Comment: This is great! especially since sometimes I forgot which clones I use with powershell's pipenv and which with WSL so `pipenv --rm` is not good enough for me in some cases, thank you!

Comment: Note this does not remove the associated Pipfile and Pipfile.lock files (in the current directory)!

Comment: Also delete the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock in the project directory by running the command "rm -rf Pipfile.lock Pipfile" in unix or linux system. I think in windows we need to use "del Pipfile" and "del Pipfile.lock" command to perform deleting those two files